# Trigger PAI after dropdown selection in module pool screen?

Tags: events, abap, dynpro

On a screen of a module pool I have a dropdown list that works fine.

[image: Definition of elements as dropdown]

How can I trigger execution of PAI immediately after the user selected a value from the dropdown box?

I'd like to change some screen properties depending on the value the user selected from the dropdown box without forcing them to to press enter after the selection.

Comment: You may link the listbox field to a user command ("ModifGruppen/Funktionen" in your screenshot)

Comment: I already tried that but I made a mistake: there must be no other mandatory field on the same screen for this to work. Works now as long I have no mandatory field.

Comment: Yeah, then you have to provide first what's mandatory. This is the way SAP works. ;)

Comment: Or define "mandatory but not blocking" i.e. "recommended".

Answer (score 1):

The field of type list control should have a function code.

In which case the selection will trigger ok_code PAI processing.

[image]